# QProcess start cmd.exe but it don't show

Tags: c++, windows, qt5

I want to start cmd.exe in the working directory with QProcess. In the task manager, the process is started but it don't show. But it works fine on linux.
Here is my code

```cpp
QString exec;
    #if (defined (_WIN32) || defined (_WIN64))
        exec = "cmd.exe";
    #elif (defined (LINUX) || defined (__linux__))
        exec = "gnome-terminal";
    #endif
    if((tabView->count() > 0) && (tabView->currentIndex() >= 0))
    {
        QDir fileDir{QFileInfo(fileName()).absoluteDir()};
        QString path      = fileDir.absolutePath();
        QProcess *process = new QProcess(this);
        process->setWorkingDirectory(path);
        process->start(exec,QStringList{});
    }
    else
    {
        QProcess *process = new QProcess(this);
        process->setWorkingDirectory(QDir::home().absolutePath());
        process->start(exec,QStringList{});
    }
```

Is there a way to solve this ?

Comment: As far as I'm aware `cmd.exe` is just a command interpreter.  It has no visual element (window etc.) associated with it.

Comment: When it starts, it shows a window to type commands. I want this command line to show but it doesn't